# Use a SQL View as a navigation property

Tags: entity-framework, t-sql, ef-code-first

I've been searching to see if what I want is possible in EF6 Code First.
I have added a View in my database.

```
CREATE VIEW MyView AS 
    SELECT x.Id, x.Something, y.SomethingElse
    FROM ....
```

I also have an entity with primary key Id:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

So, now, what I would like to do, is add a navigation property to MyEntity, like so:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<MyViewEntity> MyView { get; set; } = new Collection<MyViewEntity>();
}
```

Note: I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22998430/how-can-you-add-a-navigation-property-on-a-view-in-ef-6-1-codefirst) question. What I would like to do is the **opposite**.

For this purpose, I have created a class and added a foreign key attribute to indicate the relationship.

```
[Table("MyViewEntity")] // Hardcoded name, no -s suffix
public class MyViewEntity
{
    public int MyEntityId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("BusinessId,StatementId")]
    public MyEntity MyEntity { get; set; }

    public int Something { get; set; }
    public int SomethingElse { get; set; }
}
```

Either I've forgotten something or what I want is not possible, because I get the error that there's a pending migration. If I run `Add-Migration test`, EF Code First tries to create a table "MyViewEntity" with the properties MyEntityId, Something, SomethingElse.

How can I tell Entity Framework that the navigation property I want to use comes from a View that's already there?